# MSDataSetGenerator Failure on 2013 Ultimate

Tags: dataset

I've just installed VS 2013 and opened an old solution; I'm getting this error:

[image: Error]

Google is turning up nothing, as well as StackExchange. I didn't realize I was this unique.

Per [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166527.aspx) I checked the registry entries. All was well, except that the assembly version was set to 10. I changed it to 12 and restarted VS. Alas, no improvement. The PublicKeyToken seems to be the same across versions.

Does anyone know how to track this down?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be the cause of it:

[image]

I took the connection information out of the .XSD and it worked just fine.